# Multiply two pandas series matching on series index

Tags: pandas, series, multiplication

I have 2 pandas series

Series 1:
2016-01-31  10
2016-01-31  20 
2016-03-31  30
2016-03-31  40

Series 2:
2016-01-31  2
2016-03-31  3

I want to multiply Series 1 and Series 2 matching on index:

Answer
2016-01-31  20
2016-01-31  40 
2016-03-31  90
2016-03-31  120

Answer (score 1):

Use [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html) with parameter `fill_value=1`:

```
s = s1.mul(s2, fill_value=1)
print (s)
2016-01-31     20
2016-01-31     40
2016-03-31     90
2016-03-31    120
dtype: int64
```